# Comparing bound between lasso and OLS

Tags: regression, lasso, high-dimensional, bounds

Assume fixed design regression model $Y = \mathbf{X} \beta + \epsilon$ with common assumptions. Lasso estimator $\hat{\beta}_\lambda$ can be shown to have the following bound.

> For any $\delta > 0$, define $\lambda_0 = \sigma\sqrt{\frac{\log\left(p/\delta\right)}{n}}$. Let $A_0 \ge 1$. With With probability at least $1-2\delta$,$$\frac{1}{2n}\left\| \mathbf{X}\hat{\beta}_\lambda - \mathbf{X}\beta^*\right\|_2^2 \le 2A_0 \lambda_0 \left\| \beta^*\right\|_1$$
>   holds.

What would be a similar bound for $\frac{1}{2n}\left\|\mathbf{X} \hat{\beta}_\text{OLS} - \mathbf{X} \beta^*\right\|_2^2$? An easy application of Markov inequality yiels
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{ \left\|\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta}_\text{OLS} -\mathbf{X}\beta^*\right\|_2^2 \le \frac{\sigma^2 p}{2\delta}\right\} \ge 1-2\delta$$

However I doubt that this is the best thing we can get.

Alternatively, I think it's also true that
$$\frac{1}{2n} \left\|\mathbf{X}\beta^* - \mathbf{X} \hat{\beta}_\text{OLS}\right\|_2^2 \le \lambda_0 \left\|\hat{\beta}_\text{OLS} - \beta^*\right\|_1$$

with high probability. But I don't know how to control $\left\|\hat{\beta}_\text{OLS} - \beta^*\right\|_1$.

My ultimate goal is to show/disprove that in situation where $n > p$ but still many true coefficients are zero or small, lasso will be "better" than OLS. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is $p$?  What is $A_0$? Where does the $\lambda$ associated with $\hat{\beta}_{\lambda}$ come into play?  As it is, one could simply observe that $\hat{\beta}_{\text{OLS}} = \hat{\beta}_0$, and there's no apparent reason why the bound wouldn't be exactly the same.

Comment: $p$ is the dimension of the true parameter $\beta*$. $A_0$ is some real number s.t. $A_0 \ge 1$. $\lambda$ obviously is the tuning parameter and $\lambda_0 = \sigma \sqrt{2\log (p/\delta) / n}$

Comment: Since $\lambda$ appears nowhere in  the expression for the bound, one assumes it holds for all $\lambda$, including $\lambda = 0$, which corresponds to the OLS estimator... so the bound you have already works for the OLS estimator, which clearly satisfies the requirement of a "similar bound"!

Comment: @jbowman Not sure if I understand you... There is no $\lambda$ in $\frac{\sigma^2 p}{2\delta}$...?

Comment: Do you see a $\lambda$ there?  I don't.  I see a $p$, a $\delta$, a $\sigma$, and a $2$.  This relates back to my initial comment, repeated in my second one:  where does $\lambda$ come into play?

Comment: @jbowman I don't understand what point you are trying to make. Yes, there is no $\lambda$ in $\frac{\sigma^2 p}{2\delta}$. And?

Comment: My first and second comments contain the point: since $\lambda$ appears nowhere in the expression for the bound, the bound must hold for all $\lambda$, including $\lambda=0$.  $\hat{\beta}_0$ is the same as the OLS estimator, therefore, the bound already holds for the OLS estimator.  Consequently, you don't need to try to find a "similar bound" at all, you already have one :)

Comment: @jbowman Oh I see. Of course, I agree that in the quoted theorem $\lambda_0$ can be $0$. But in that case, the statement becomes "in-sample error is zero with probability greater than some negative number" (because you need $p = \delta$ then), not very useful :(

Comment: @jbowman But yes, I agree that your points will all go through mathematically.

Comment: But $\lambda$ need not be the same as $\lambda_0$, right?  If they are the same, you should clarify that in the question, as your subscripts are for $\lambda$, not $\lambda_0$.